# c++ templated container scanner

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

here's today's dilemma:

suppose I've

```
class A{
  public:
   virtual void doit() = 0;
}
```

then various subclasses of A, all implementing their good doit method. Now suppose I want to write a function that takes two iterators (one at the beginning of a sequence, the other at the end). The sequence is a sequence of A subclasses like say `list<A*>` or vector... The function should call all the doit methods while scanning the iterators... How to do this? I've thought of:

```
template<typename Iterator> void doList(Iterator &begin, Iterator &end) {
    for (; begin != end; begin++) {
        A *elem = (serializable*) *begin;
        elem.doIt();
    }
}
```

but gives weird errors... do you have better ideas or specific information? Is it possible to use `list<A>` instead of `list<A*>`?

Comment: Can you please give some examples of the weird errors you're getting?

Comment: Nit: Are you sure you want to pass the iterators by reference?

Comment: Yes, of course you can use `list<A>` but then we'd need to see the actual call to suggest better.

Comment: Um, I don't see how he can use list<A> if A is abstract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `std::foreach` for that:

```
std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fun( &A::doIt ) );
```

The `std::mem_fun` will create an object that calls the given member function for it's `operator()` argument.  The `for_each`  will call this object for every element within `v.begin()` and `v.end()`.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think you need the cast? If it is a collection of A * you should just be able to say:

```
(*begin)->doIt();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide error messages to get better answers.

In your code, the first thing that comes to mind is to use

```
elem->doIt();
```

What is the "serializable" type ?

Comment: sorry serializable stands for A. How can the compiler know that elem has a doIt method???

Comment: Because it knows that elem is of type A*